# WPF: Drawing Geometries from a List<Geometry>

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to learn wpf and in the process I'm basically trying to load a series of paths and draw them.  I have several test "files" that contain certain samples of different geometry types.  The "files" each have a different number of shapes.

What is the best way to load these files into a WPF application.  I obviously don't want to create individual paths in the XAML and so there is a better way, I just don't know it.  I'd still like the shapes to be hit-testable for example.  I don't want to just do a union and convert the multiple shapes to a single set of shapes.

I'm doing this in C# 4.0.

EDIT: I've basically just serialized the coordinates of various polygons to text files.  I then create Paths from these text files.  If I have a list containing 3 polygons, how do I render them without explicitly creating 3 paths in the XAML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read them in (say from a file) and use the `XamlReader` to create concrete instances of them. you can store them in an `ObservableCollection`, and then bind said collection to an `ItemsControl` where you have specified the panel as a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking [Shapefiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile), then [Mapsui](http://mapsui.codeplex.com/) would be one good option.
I prefer not re-inventing the wheel all the time..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class, then once you have concrete objects you can easily add them wherever parent control you wish.

Use [`XamlReader.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx) if you want to load it via a stream (e.g. [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)), or [`XamlReader.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse.aspx) if they are in available strings.

These methods will return the root of the constructed object tree (which might even be a `Path` as well).